AudioCapture and $AudioInputDevices never detect my microphone
My friend and I are both having the same problem.  My microphone works fine in all other apps, except Mathematica can't detect any input devices.  Has anyone found a solution to this?
Windows 11 Pro.  Permissions for microphone are set correctly.

Update audio drivers, delete all personal Mathematica folders  in /users/../AppData. Personal experience 2021: hp-windows realtek drivers on notebooks needed special updates

Thanks for responding.  This is a brand new install of Windows 11, everything has been updated.  I'll have my friend do this since his PC is older.

I got this to work using the following method.
FindDevices[]
DeviceOpen["Name of device"]
AudioCapture[]
